# How to properly shutdown executor services with Spring?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, junit, executorservice

I have a command line application that uses a Spring-managed bean that's composed of a java `ExecutorService` created with:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Now, I want my service to shutdown when my application shuts down, so I made my bean implement the `DisposableBean` interface and have a destroy method such as:

```
public void destroy(){
  service.shutdown();
}
```

Then I might be tempted to do something like register a shutdown hook on the Spring context. However I found out (the hard way, i.e., in a pre-production release) that this doesn't work: the shutdown hook doesn't get called before the `ExecutorService.shutdown()` method is called, causing a classic catch 22 problem (it does get called on interruption, i.e., if I hit Ctrl-C while the application is running). This escaped my unit tests because for some reason it seems to work fine from within JUnit, which is still puzzling me: what does JUnit do differently?

The solution I found so far is to explicitly call `ApplicationContext.close()` right before I exit my main function. I was wondering if there was a better solution to this and what are the best practices for having flexible thread pools managed by Spring. Also what if my bean is **not** directly managed by Spring but is created by a bean managed by Spring? Should I just cascade the calls to `destroy()`? Wouldn't this be very error prone?

I appreciate any comments, suggestions, further reading, RTFMs, magic recipes.

Thanks!

Comment: PS: what if I want to move my command line application to an app server such as Tomcat? Does anything change?

Comment: Including the title and your PS I  count *seven* (7!) question marks.  :-)   May get better responses if you ask just one specific question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you aware that this:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

can be replaced with this:

```
<bean id="service" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
      factory-method="newFixedThreadPool" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg value="4"/>
</bean>
```

The spring context then manages, more directly, the shutdown of your executor service--and it can be more easily reused.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However in some cases I'd rather create my beans programmatically rather than through configuration, e.g., if I will not know how many beans I'll need until runtime or the definition of a particular bean will come from an external source, e.g., database or message queue.

Comment: Count my upvote down, it's invalid. This does not work but results in `InvalidArgumentException` while initializing the Spring Context.

Answer (score 9):

Per official Spring documentation, when using annotation-based configuration, for [destroyMethod](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#destroyMethod--) field of `@Bean`, Spring's default behavior is to automatically invoke public, no-arg methods named `close` or `shutdown` when the application context is being closed.

> As a convenience to the user, the container will attempt to infer a
>   destroy method against an object returned from the @Bean method. For
>   example, given an @Bean method returning an Apache Commons DBCP
>   BasicDataSource, the container will notice the close() method
>   available on that object and automatically register it as the
>   destroyMethod. This 'destroy method inference' is currently limited to
>   detecting only public, no-arg methods named 'close' or 'shutdown'. The
>   method may be declared at any level of the inheritance hierarchy and
>   will be detected regardless of the return type of the @Bean method
>   (i.e., detection occurs reflectively against the bean instance itself
>   at creation time).

To re-iterate, this is the default behavior for *annotation-driven* configuration when a destroy method is not explicitly set. If this behavior is undesired explicitly setting destroy method to an empty string will disable this "feature":

> To disable destroy method inference for a particular @Bean, specify an
>   empty string as the value, e.g. @Bean(destroyMethod=""). Note that the
>   DisposableBean and the Closeable/AutoCloseable interfaces will
>   nevertheless get detected and the corresponding destroy/close method
>   invoked.

On the other hand, when using XML configuration, this is *not* the default behavior... To achieve parity, [destroy-method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean) can be explicitly set to `(inferred)`. Refer to the [Destruction callbacks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean) and [Default initialization and destroy methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-default-init-destroy-methods]) sections in the official docs for details.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Spring's TaskExecutor, which can be configured with a thread pool.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

Comment: I don't think that will fit my use case. I have a lot of inter-task synchronization that needs to be performed (e.g., barriers) and I'd rather have more control over it by explicitly using executors and custom tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add the config based ExecutorService bean creation to [@Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516297/1369136)

```
@Bean("fixedThreadPool")
public ExecutorService fixedThreadPool() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I got null point exception whit the instance of ExecutorService where I have autowired it. Could you  comment me what would be the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@PreDestroy` annotation as well:

```java
@Component
public class MyService {
  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

  @PreDestroy
  @SneakyThrows
  void shutdownExecutor() {
    executor.shutdown();
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      executor.shutdownNow();
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively if the `ExecutorService` itself is a bean:

```java
@Bean(name = "fixedThreadPool", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public ExecutorService fixedThreadPool() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
}
```