# Is spring taking care of shutting down your ExecutorService?

Tags: java, spring, executorservice, shutdown

In my config class I have a bean for FixedThreadPool

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService fixedThreadPool() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);
}
```

and I autowire it later in some class. As I was researching, I came across that this was the best way to do a shutdown of an executor service, as per [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
   void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

But I also found that [spring does that for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516131/how-to-properly-shutdown-executor-services-with-spring), if your ExecutorService is a bean. My question is - is this true? If it is, it's certainly easier, since I am in doubt of where to put the code mention above. If I put it in the class where I am using this bean, I might use this bean in some other classes in the future, and it just seems wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Spring does that for you, but it will destroy the beans only when the container is shutting down, you might want to shutdown the executory service once it has processed all the tasks. You can create ExecutorService bean as prototype but since spring will not completely manage its lifecycle you'll have to call its destroy method yourself once your task is done.

Comment: How does it do that? Does it have special support for `ExecutorService` so that you don't have to specify any lifecycle methods yourself?

Comment: Answering my own question: By default, Spring looks for `close()` and `shutdown()` methods on the `@Bean`. Unless you configure it otherwise, it will call those.

Comment: @Raghvendra
From [Spring Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype), I think that if the scope of bean in my case is prototype, Spring won't do a shutdown for me. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I am referring to the next-to-last paragraph in this section.

Comment: @MelissaGreen Yes i stand corrected. spring will not completely manage the lifecycle of prototype beans

Comment: I got null pointer exception. I think it is because of that my class is a POJO where I am autowiring the service. In fact this class in a Camel Processor

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring calls only shutdown method of the ExecutorService.
After calling the destroy method, the spring considers its work completed.
Shutdown is an asynchronous method and does not block the destroy method. It doesn't wait for the ExecutorService to complete its work.
And after that, the Spring application simply stops without waiting for the tasks in the queue to complete.
There are several approaches to avoid the problem.

1. We can keep the default behavior and use ThreadPools with a queue size of zero. It will wait for tasks already in threads.
2. We can use Queue and define our own destroy method containing the below code.

**Custom destroy method**

```
void customDestroyMethod() {
    super.shutdown();
    this.awaitTermination(max_time_you_can_wait_ExecutorService, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```